# CAS 3 setup questions

Tags: cas

I am new to use CAS .
I am trying to setup CAS 3 on windows server , I would like to make it to connect windows Active Directory server for authentication , I find this URL and have follow it to setup , but I am wonder why the steps do not involved CAS server ( I mean there is no need to use CAS server program ) , it only config the Tomcat server to connect the AD server , I have followed the steps but cannot connect my AD server .
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/End-to-end+Windows+Example 
I am confused the concept , why the steps no need to use download CAS server ? 
Would you advise any URL that is useful for setup CAS 3 ?

Very thanks

Answer (score -1):

Why don't know you make your life easier and use a cloud provider for CAS servers: https://www.casinthecloud.com...